# Required Recursive function for parent child relation tree?

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach, codeigniter-3

> Scenario:

i have course that has shifts(morning ,evening ect.) [*course is parent of shift*].
and for every shift there are sections (A Green,A blue ,B ect)[*shift is parent of sections*].

> graph:

[image]

Current record i get by joins :

```
    $this->db->select("sections.section_id,c.course_id,s.id as shift_id");
    $this->db->from($this->_table);
    $this->db->join('shift s', 's.id = sections.shift_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('courses c', 's.course_id = c.course_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('employees e', 'e.employee_id = sections.head_id', 'left');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->order_by('section_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->where('c.course_id',$course_id);
```

> query result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [course_id] => 3
            [section_id] => 5
            [shift_id] => 7
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 2
        [section_id] => 4
        [shift_id] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 2
        [section_id] => 3
        [shift_id] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 1
        [section_id] => 2
        [shift_id] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 1
        [section_id] => 1
        [shift_id] => 4
    )

)
```

Want result like this:

```
Array
(
    [course_id 3] => Array
        (
            [shift id] => array
                                (
                                 [section_id] => 5
                                )
        )
[course_id 2] => Array
    (
        [shift_morning] =>array
                            (
                             [section_id] => 4
                            )
        [shift_noon] =>array
                            (
                             [section_id] => 3
                            )
    )
 [course_id 1] => Array
    (
        [shift_morning] =>array
                            (
                             [section_id] => 2
                            )
        [shift_noon] =>array
                            (
                             [section_id] => 1
                            )
    )
)
```

any can help please.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: rearrangement of result ,on the basis of parent child relation .
i know sql don't support hierarchical data.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: What tables/columns are used? How do you get first array? Show code before results.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to extrapolate the required information to properly set your shift key from your posted information however all you have to do is modify the switch statement to properly set this key:

```
$this->db->select("sections.section_id,c.course_id,s.id as shift_id");
$this->db->from($this->_table);
$this->db->join('shift s', 's.id = sections.shift_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('courses c', 's.course_id = c.course_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('employees e', 'e.employee_id = sections.head_id', 'left');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->order_by('section_id', 'desc');
$this->db->where('c.course_id',$course_id);
$query = $this->db->get();

$results = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    switch ($row['shift_id']) {
        case 5:
            $shift = 'morning';
        break;

        case 6:
            $shift = 'noon';
        break;
    }

    $results['course_id '.$row['course_id']]['shift_'.$shift]['section_id'] = $row['section_id'];
}
```